# On Selenium IDE, how to assert the text value in between tags?

Tags: selenium-ide

The source code reads: `<div class="qa">on</div>`

And I want to assert in Selenium IDE that the value in between `<div ...>` and `</div>` is "`on`".

I tried to use assertValue and assertAttribute, but got an error with both commands. If I use assertElementPresent for the `xpath=//div[@class='qa']`/, it would pass, but it wouldn't assert that the value in between the `<div>`'s is "`on`".

Comment: What code did you wrote on the Selenium IDE?  Could you show your code?

Comment: I know this is from years ago. This comment is for people searching for this in the future. Using `assertValue` is specifically for elements that have a value attribute (input, select, etc). As the answer below rightly states `assertText` is the way to go, but it doesn't include that it's the one to use for text between the tags (div, span, p, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `assertText` (or `verifyText` if the test should not halt on failure):

```
assertText  xpath=//div[@class='qa']  exact:on
```

From the reference:

> **assertText(locator, pattern)**
>
> Generated from **getText(locator)**
>
> Arguments:
>
> - locator - an element locator
>
> Returns:
>
> - the text of the element
>
> Gets the text of an element. This works for any element that contains text. This command uses either the textContent (Mozilla-like
>   browsers) or the innerText (IE-like browsers) of the element, which is
>   the rendered text shown to the user.

Comment: How did you find out about the "exact:" part? Does it mean that without it, it would be searching for the presence of the "on" as a substring, i.e. would also match "strong"?